# Accordion container with article tag

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

According to the documentation of F6 we can use the accordion container with something else than a *ul* tag. Or, I can't get it to work with an *article* tag.

The problem seems to be caused by the fact that *.accordion-title* isn't the direct child of *.accordion-item*. Unfortunately, in my use case, I need to wrap the *a* tag with the *.accordion-title* class inside an heading tag.

Does anyone would know how to solve that issue?

Thanks,

Here's an example of my use case :

```
<div class="accordion" enter code here
      data-multi-expand="true" 
      data-allow-all-closed="true" 
      data-accordion>
  <article class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <header>
      <h3>
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Group Name</a>
      </h3>
    </header>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: You could catch the click on the header / h3 and do it on the a tag instead (preventDefault + click()).

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out, it doesn't have to do with the `<article>` tag but rather that a direct child click trigger is needed.

Example of it working with `<article>`

https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/pGKZYg

Without JS modification, it may not work the way you want it to.

Comment: That's exactly what I use for the moment but it kills the semantic of my `<article>` since there's no heading :). Guess I'll have to dive in the JS code. Thanks for confirming that `<a>` needs to be a direct child. I wonder if I should open an issue on GitHub for that tho.